# parsing ambiguity in antlr4

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to recognize list comprehension expressions like `a for b in c for d in e` and I have the following grammar:

```
iter : 'for' ID 'in' expr ;

expr : ID 
     | expr iter+  # listcomp
     | ID + ID   # binary
     ;
```

but given `a for b in c for d in e` it is parsed as:

```
(a for b in (c for d in e))
```

i.e., a `listcomp` of `listcomp`

rather than:

```
(a (for b in c) (for d in e))
```

i.e., a single `listcomp` with two `iter`s. How should I change the grammar to get that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associativity resolves the ambiguity:

```
grammar Compre;
program: iter+;
iter :  expr (forr ID inr expr)+  ;
expr : ID             # IdExpr
     | expr iter+     # listcomp
     | expr '+' expr  # BinaryExp
     | NUM            # NumExpr
     ;
forr : <assoc=left>'for' ;
inr : <assoc=right> 'in'     ;
NUM : [0-9]+;
ID : [a-z];
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Try this grammar on your various inputs.  It parses both inputs you've supplied.[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am hoping to not add parentheses to resolve the ambiguity (with associativity I suppose?), just like in standard python.

Comment: Thank you @TomServo. I actually needed to modify my grammar a bit (see above) by allowing `listcomp` to take an `expr` rather than `ID` as in python (e.g., `1+x for x in l`). That seems to have broken your solution :(

Comment: @JRR Please see my latest edit.  This handles the expression at the beginning also.